# 400 Bad Request: POST request using javax.ws.rs and Json jackson

Tags: java, json, javax.ws.rs

I am trying to make a POST with javax. Keep getting the 400 bad request response code. It suggests that there is something wrong with the json being sent(?) I have checked the json a hundred times, it looks pretty good to me. What am I missing?

enter code here

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Entity payload = Entity.json("{  'offset': 0,  'limit': 15,  'query': 'ad',  'search_type': 'global'}");
Response response = client.target("https:******/contacts/search")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("authToken", ACCESS_TOKEN)
                .post(payload);
```

Comment: can you post what the http header looks like? 
Also, are you setting a url?

Comment: I think your url is mangled. it should be https://... shouldn't it?

Comment: JSON syntax requires a double quote character `"` not a `'`. Can this cause your issue?

Comment: @wero modified it to {  "offset": 0,  "limit": 15,  "query": "ad",  "search_type": "global"} --> This gives out a syntax error. Tried few combinations, same issue.

Comment: Did you escape it like `Entity.json("{  \"offset\":...`

Comment: Escaping worked! I had not escaped it. This is my first time, I appreciate your help. Really, I mean, REALLY.

Comment: @pascalsAger great! good luck